# WARNING: Attempt to convert JsonElement from GSON. This functionality is deprecated. Diagnostic stacktrace follows with Selenium

Tags: java, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gson

I upgraded my selenium and chromedriver to the latest version. 
After doing so, when creating a new chromedriver instance with the same (still valid) DesiredCapabilities object, I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: Attempt to convert JsonElement from GSON. This functionality is deprecated.
```

Did anyone else had this problem/ know how to solve/supress it?

I should note that I ran a test suite and it passed OK, just printed this warning.

Ran it locally on MacOS and on a remote linux host.

Details:

MacOS:

```
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'mac-lap-13', ip: '0.0.0.0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
```

Linux:

```
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
 System info: host: 'Automation', ip: '0.0.0.0', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
```

Full stackTrace:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db) on port 46910
Only local connections are allowed.
Aug 09, 2018 3:52:54 PM org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput lambda$new$11
WARNING: Attempt to convert JsonElement from GSON. This functionality is deprecated. Diagnostic stacktrace follows
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Stack trace to determine cause of warning
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'mac-lap-13', ip: '0.0.0.0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$11(JsonOutput.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$SafeBiConsumer.accept(JsonOutput.java:394)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(JsonOutput.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.convertUsingMethod(JsonOutput.java:300)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$13(JsonOutput.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$SafeBiConsumer.accept(JsonOutput.java:394)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(JsonOutput.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$null$20(JsonOutput.java:161)
    at java.util.TreeMap.forEach(TreeMap.java:1005)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1505)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$21(JsonOutput.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$SafeBiConsumer.accept(JsonOutput.java:394)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(JsonOutput.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$null$20(JsonOutput.java:161)
    at com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableBiMap.forEach(SingletonImmutableBiMap.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$21(JsonOutput.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$SafeBiConsumer.accept(JsonOutput.java:394)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(JsonOutput.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(JsonOutput.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toJson(Json.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:142)
    at com.d5.automation.uitester.webdriver.ClientReactTest.setUpForTests(ClientReactTest.java:227)
    at com.d5.automation.uitester.webdriver.ClientReactTest.startWebDriver(ClientReactTest.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.rules.Verifier$1.evaluate(Verifier.java:35)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(JUnitCore.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(JUnitCore.java:49)
    at com.d5.automation.uitester.CiCdTests.ciCdFrontEndTest(CiCdTests.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)

Aug 09, 2018 3:52:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned you have upgraded *Selenium* and *ChromeDriver* to the latest version i.e **Selenium v3.13.0** and **ChromeDriver v2.41** and created a new *ChromeDriver* instance with the (still valid) `DesiredCapabilities` type object, **yes** is still works. But you must have seen the **deprecation** *warning* as follows:

[image: deprecation]

Further when you will execute your code block you will find the following *INFO*:

```
Aug 10, 2018 1:02:08 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab) on port 44262
Only local connections are allowed.
Aug 10, 2018 1:02:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Google
```

So as per best practices you must start using the `new ChromeOptions()` as follows:

```
package demo; //replace by your own package name

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class A_Chrome_Options_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
        opt.merge(cap);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

About the *WARNING*:

```
WARNING: Attempt to convert JsonElement from GSON. This functionality is deprecated. Diagnostic stacktrace follows
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Stack trace to determine cause of warning
```

*Release Notes* of **Selenium v3.13.0** clearly mentions:

> - Introduced our own JSON parser and outputter, allowing GSON to be removed from our dependencies.

Hence you see the error.

### Solution

To get rid of the *warning* and errors upgrade to **Selenium v3.14.0**, where *Release Notes* clearly mentions:

> - Completely removed the GSON dependency. We now use reflection to try and find the class.

Comment: This works fine, so thanks! just to note, I thought 3.13.0 is the latest because the version in the official website (https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) is yet to be updated (for now). Maven website on the other hand, shows 3.14.0 as the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Use the last version of org.seleniumhq.selenium for Chrome WebDriver and following code:

```
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.merge(cap);
    new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  It's a perfectly viable option to take your existing DesiredCapabilities and merge them into the new ChromeOptions object..