# Selenium - Chromeoptions - JsonException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a newbie to Automation.Trying to execute below code. Its giving me jsonexception.
I have read on previous answers that desired capabilities is deprecated. I have also tried using chromeoption.merge(capabilities) but even that is not working. Code below. Please help

```
Exception : 
WARNING: Attempt to convert JsonElement from GSON. This functionality is deprecated. Diagnostic stacktrace follows
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Stack trace to determine cause of warning
```

```
public class base {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public Properties prop;

    public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {
        prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                "E:\\SeleniumWorkspace\\E2EProject\\src\\main\\java\\resources\\data.properties");
        prop.load(fis);
        String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");

        if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Setups\\chromedriver_win32Chrome90\\chromedriver.exe");

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
            options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);


        }

        if (browserName.equals("firefox")) {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767892/warning-attempt-to-convert-jsonelement-from-gson-this-functionality-is-depreca/55608577#55608577 you may be using an old selenium version

Comment: @art_architect - In the thread that you have shared, they are saying the same thing about merging chrome options with capabilities which is no longer supported. I am using selenium version 3.141.59 and observing the issue on the same. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: The thing is, i ran your code and it runs fine with 3.141.59. Are you using a Gson jar/maven import by any chance?

Comment: Yes I am using maven setup. Mentioned the maven dependencies in pom.xml and I am not sure about Gson jar.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any issue with your code. However, If I may suggest, you may use the below instead of setting the property each time

**To automatically set the property for chrome:**

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

Go here to see for other drivers: [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)

Now that being said, I think you might be using an old version of Selenium, add the below in your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I am using the above dependencies for running in "headless" mode and my tests do not throw any error for ChromeOptions.

Comment: This dependency i have already added in my pom.xml but no luck yet.

Comment: Okay. Can you add something like this ->

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors");
webDriver = new ChromeDriver( options);

I  believe this should help with your test. Can you try and let us know

Comment: Alright,  one last try though, can you try with the WebDriverManager mentioned in my answer instead of writing "System.setProperty()", use "WebDriverManager.chromeDriver().setup()". Before doing this, kindly add the dependency of it by going to that link. This has to work. If not I am just thinking maybe you have an older version of chromeDriver. What is your chrome version? 

Chrome and ChromeDriver version has to match. Try to use the  same .exe file for the version you have in your desktop for the browser